# How to optimize do-while loops?

Tags: java, loops

I want to execute a loop as long as a certain condition applies. At the end, I want to return the value that was last being found inside the loop.

Non-realworld example:

```
teststring = "        abcde";

String letter = null;
do {
    letter = reader.read(); //reads the teststring char by char
} while (letter.equals(" "));
return letter; //return "a"
```

Could this be optimized from the coding point of view, eg transform it from a do-while loop to just a while-loop?

Comment: What makes you think this is not efficient?

Comment: Why would a while loop be more efficient than a do-while one?

Comment: That's the question: is it or not? If not, will that's fine.

Comment: Use a profiler and find out what eats the performance. Asked to place a bet my guess would be the "*char by char*" part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Java 1.7 or 1.8, you can do this:

```
while((letter=reader.read()).equals(" ")){
}
return letter;
```

Comment: No, this will return the first " "

Comment: The nested `return` means this will only loop once.

Comment: That will return the first white space it encounters.

Comment: Editted, this will loop until a, then the while loop finishes and function returns a.

Comment: It can be an another Reader implementation, the post doesnt specify that.

Comment: It does say in the comment `char` not String.

Answer (score 1):

if you are reading from a [Reader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) it returns an int which is the `char` or -1 if at the end of input.

```
int ch;
while((ch = reader.read()) == ' ');
return ch;
```

Note: " " is a String and ' ' is a char.

Answer (score 1):

No sure about what is more efficient but you could do something like:

```
`return teststring.trim().charAt(0);
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey I probably should have included a test for `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` after `trim()` since it can return an empty String in which case `charAt(0)` will fail. but you get the picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
      ...
} while (<condition>);
```

I am going to explain your question on do/while vs while alone.

The do is only a label.  It has no impact on efficiency.  The while at the bottom is effectively an if(condition) goto line #, where line # is the do.  The "do" is simply a way of telling the compiler what number you want in that goto statement at the bottom.

Putting the while statement at the top would actually be less efficient because it means the condition has to be evaluated on the first iteration.  Perhaps your reader does need to be checked on the first iteration, then it should be a while statement, but that requires more work, you see?

Second even transforming it to only a while statement, still places an unconditional goto at the bottom, with a conditional goto on the top, so even though it looks like less code, it could possibly be more.

Comment: Since my response doesn't depend on OP's code in the loop being valid, I factored it out.  But it's premature to say what reader() returns, because he's not included its type (you assume it's java.io.Reader) and it requires assuming his code does not actually work in a question about making the code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to just use [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and a [`For Each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
String teststring = "        abcde";
for (char ch : teststring.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch != ' ') return ch; // <-- 'a'
}
throw new ParseException("Whitespace only");
```

But, you could use a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) and you're using `char` (a primitive), so I think you've asked for

```
String teststring = "        abcde";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(teststring);
try {
    int letter;
    do {
        letter = reader.read();
    } while (letter == ' ');
    return ((char) letter);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
throw new ParseException("Whitespace only");
```

or return a default value if the character isn't found.

Comment: This will be an infinite loop if you only have spaces left in the first case, and a compile error in the second.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I switched the order around, and I think I fixed the issue you're referring to. What compile error though?

Comment: You are not returning anything after the for loop.